# Is Hazelcast Client thread safe?

Tags: hazelcast

I cannot find this in the [docs](http://hazelcast.org/docs/3.2/manual/html-single/hazelcast-documentation.html#java-client) or [javadocs](http://hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/client/HazelcastClient.html): do I need to create one client per thread or is a client created by:

```
client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(cfg);
```

thread safe?

Answer (score 9):

The client is thread-safe. Also when you get e.g. an IMap from it, it also is thread-safe.

```
HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(cfg)
IMap map = client.getMap("map");
```

So you can share this client instance with all your threads in the JVM.

Comment: Thanks! I know your background ;) but is this documented somewhere?

Comment: It is documented in the Hazelcast book.

http://hazelcast.org/mastering-hazelcast/#cover

Comment: hy peter? "So you can share this client instance with all your threads in the JVM." how much scalable it is when we share it across all thread?

Comment: It depends on how many threads you have and what they are doing to the client. Most of our stress tests we have 40 concurrent threads pounding the client-instance and it works fine.

Comment: @pveentjer so how many clientinstance should we create for a server instance?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You create a single client instance per JVM for the whole cluster.

Comment: @pveentjer seen you write excellent book about HazelCast. Think you have to know answer to my question. May you look at it please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109127/hazelcast-will-map-reduce-tasks-be-launched-few-times-if-we-duplicate-data-betw. Thanks!

Comment: @pveentjer Is the JCache interface thread safe also? (client and server implementations). Thanks!