# Hazelcast client multiple instances

Tags: hazelcast

I want to access data from hazelcast server using hazelcast client. I am using threads in my hazelcast client. When threads are execuring parallely, if first thread executes `client.shutdown()` and another threads in execution,

My program throws  exception as `Internal executor rejected task:  because client is shutting down`.

What's the solution for this?

Comment: dear Hemnath, kindly pick a correct answer for this question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast Client is thread safe and can be reused. I would suggest to shutdown your client on your application shutdown.

See similar SO question [Is Hazelcast Client thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567894/is-hazelcast-client-thread-safe)

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have "destructors", so you'll need to find some kind of "hook". You can add a JVM shutdown hook if it's a console application, use Spring's DisposableBean assuming you use Spring (who doesn't nowadays?) or put it in the Webapp session listener if it is hosted inside a Web container like Tomcat. There are many options. That's where your Hazelcast client shutdown call belongs. Otherwise it is thread-safe.